# OSX Terminal opens default Python instead of Anaconda

Tags: python, bash, macos, python-2.7, anaconda

I've always used python with the terminal, and by typing `python` it would open Python 3.5 Anaconda, where I have saved many libraries that I usually need. Early today I tried installing something and I must've messed up because now it always opens Python 2.7 Default. I Googled and searched over here and many suggested to modify the bash_profile, which I did many times.
If I type `export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:"$PATH"` in the terminal it opens correctly the Anaconda version of Python, but every time I  reopen the terminal I have to type it again. As I said, I tried to modify the bash profile putting `export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:"$PATH"` first, I tried doing `source ~/.bash_profile`, but still nothing. 
My bash profile right now is the following, it looks kind of messy because I tried some "variations".

[bash profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4cXb.png)

Comment: Have you tried using `python2` or `python3`?

Comment: You've setup your .bash_profile to repeatively update your path; this is a pretty confusing practice. I'd sort this out by having only one export of the your path with all the references you need.  From the shell, make it easy to look at your current path with:  echo $PATH | tr -s ":" "\n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the problem might be the Homebrew part of your profile at the bottom.

It puts `/usr/local/bin/` at the front of the path.

`which python` would tell you which python you are about to get.  And `echo $PATH` will tell you the overall path you're about to use.  Post the results of those.

So from your comments you're running the python from Homebrew and you need to move that part of your profile to the top.

Comment: You're right, I was about to add the `echo $PATH` output:      `/usr/local/bin:/Users/Norman/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Users/Norman/anaconda/bin:/Users/Norman/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/Norman/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin`

Comment: which -a may be more helpful, so the OP can see the various versions of python in the path.

Comment: And indeed, trying `which python` outputs `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Comment: It works, you're right, I thought that the bottom part was added to the bottom part of the PATH. Thank you so much.